# How can I see a list of currently dormant cronjobs that have not yet ran?

Tags: cron, kubernetes, openshift, minishift

After triggering the following from my terminal, I have been unable to find a way to list Cronjobs running, but dormant and prior to their first run:

```
oc run pi --image=perl --schedule='*/1 * * * *' \
    --restart=OnFailure --labels parent="cronjobpi" \
    --command -- perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(2000)'
```

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html

For cronjobs that are once a month, I would like to see them.
I was expecting something like:

```
oc get cronjobs
```

But have found nothing like this. Is there anything I can do to list jobs either through the CLI or web interface to list cronjobs specifically?

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you provisioning? Are you using Minishift? Also which _oc_ client are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenShift 3.6, I have no issues with running:

```
$ oc get cronjobs
NAME      SCHEDULE       SUSPEND   ACTIVE    LAST-SCHEDULE
hello     */2 * * * *    False     0         Fri, 21 Jul 2017 14:02:00 +1000
```

When the cronjob time arrives a job is created from the job template.

```
$ oc get jobs
NAME               DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
hello-1500609360   1         1            38m
hello-1500609420   1         1            37m
hello-1500609600   1         1            34m
hello-1500609660   1         1            32m
```

Don't know why at this point, but `oc describe cronjob` doesn't work in 3.6-rc.0 though. Have already asked why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search for cronjobs and list them specifically.

This will give the jobs that have run:

```
oc get jobs
```

This will describe what cron jobs have been defined:

```
oc get cronjob
```

This will show the details of cronjob *my_cron_job*:

```
oc describe cronjob/my_cron_job
```